# How to show firestore all document fields on PaginatedDataTable or datatable with complex query?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an app with datatable and pagination. I am tried to download all my data on firebase. But I can not get it. Also, If There is a error. My code shows me warning message. But It is not show it. Only I get blank datatable.

Here what I did:

I have created an object that named kasalar.
I have uploaded my firebase data.
I have built a stream builder in my flutter app.
Lastly, I have created a datatable.

My purpose is:
I want to download all my data for putting to my pagination widget.

Here is the more details:

[image]

I want to access last document's value for putting to pagitination cells.

Kasalar class:

```
class Kasalar {

  String id;
  String kasa_adi;
  String doviz_cinsi;
  String acilis_bakiyesi;
  String olusturulma_tarihi;
  String aktivite;

  Kasalar({ required this.id , required this.kasa_adi , required this.doviz_cinsi , required this.acilis_bakiyesi, required this.olusturulma_tarihi , required this.aktivite});

  factory Kasalar.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return Kasalar(
      id:  snapshot.id,
      kasa_adi : snapshot["kasa_adi"],
      doviz_cinsi: snapshot["doviz_cinsi"],
      acilis_bakiyesi: snapshot["acilis_bakiyesi"],
      olusturulma_tarihi: snapshot["olusturulma_tarihi"],
      aktivite: snapshot["aktivite"],
    );


  }


}
```

The main page:

```
final DataTableSource _data_kasa = MyKasaData();


   List<Kasalar> kasalar = []  ;
     Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Container(
    
                  child: StreamBuilder(
    
    
                      stream: firestore.collection("Users").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email).collection("kasalar").snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snap) {
    
                 //   users = snap.data.docs.map((e) => Kasalar.fromMap(e.data)).toList();
    
                     final DataTableSource _allKasas = MyKasaData(snap.document);  // I could not put snap.document
                        if(snap.hasData){
                          return PaginatedDataTable(
                            header: const Text("Header Text"),
    
                            columns: const [
    
    
                              DataColumn(label: Text('Kasa Adi')),
                              DataColumn(label: Text('Döviz Cinsi')),
                              DataColumn(label: Text('Açılıs Bakiyesi')),
                              DataColumn(label: Text('Oluşturulma Tarihi')),
                              DataColumn(label: Text('Aktif/Pasif')),
    
                            ],
                            source: _allUsers, // ıt is useless
                          );
                        }
                        else{
                          return new Text('No data...');
                        }
                      })
    
                ),
              ),
```

My datatablesource:

```
class MyKasaData extends DataTableSource {


  SideBarController sideBarController = Get.put(SideBarController());

   List<Kasalar> kasalar = [];



  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow.byIndex(cells: [
      DataCell(Text(kasalar[index].id)),
      DataCell(Text(kasalar[index].kasa_adi)),
      DataCell(Text(kasalar[index].acilis_bakiyesi)),
      DataCell(Text(kasalar[index].doviz_cinsi)),
      DataCell(Text(kasalar[index].olusturulma_tarihi)),
    ], index: index);
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get rowCount => kasalar.length;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what's not working the way you expect.